# Google map error with angular + javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm not very good with Angular and Javascript. I want to run an existing application in local which use google map.

The page loads, and should display a map. But I got those errors :

```
js?v=3&callback=angular2GoogleMapsLazyMapsAPILoader:42 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
_.Hb @ js?v=3&callback=angular2GoogleMapsLazyMapsAPILoader:42
(anonymous) @ common.js:54
(anonymous) @ common.js:152
c @ common.js:48
(anonymous) @ AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2F167.99.133.34%3A4200%2F%23%2Fpages%2Fgyms%2Fadd&callback=_xdc_._hrm6mx&token=23882:1
util.js:228 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

I have generated new API key today, but I do not know where to put it since it's an angular library.

In my chrome debugger, I can see that my error is probably coming from this call

```
"js?v=3&callback=angular2GoogleMapsLazyMapsAPILoader:64"


 <script type="text/javascript" async="" defer="" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
    v=3&amp;callback=angular2GoogleMapsLazyMapsAPILoader"></script>
```

Have you please any idea about that ?

Comment: You need a `key` parameter for `maps.googleapis.com`

Comment: yeah but where to put it, since I do not have access to those files ( common.js ) is an internal file of the library I think

Comment: `src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"`.
You can even use this simple angularjs maps plugin library to simplify your code https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps

Comment: starting from 11 june 2018 ... is not possible use google maps without a key  .. this error is related  to the fatc that you have not a google map key and the google policies are changed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to put this 
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourKeyIsHere&libraries=places" async defer></script>`

into Angular project: index.html